# Are there threading or concurrency issues when multiple users call shell scripts from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

If we have a rails app that calls various scripts (sh, bash, perl) on remote servers, should we be concerned with those scripts blocking other users from hitting the servers at the same time?  Does anyone have experience with these issues and is willing to start a conversation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have experience with rails, However bash, shell perl scripts all run on individual processes. So multiple users shouldn't be blocked from executing these scripts at the same time merely another process is started to execute the script. Depending on what these scripts are doing you will run into concurency problems though if two people are trying to access the change the same data or their scripts are changing data that has dependancies elsewhere in the system